# ActiveAdmin doesn't recognize "self" within a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When I `GET` `/admin/consoles/1/edit`, for instance, this happens:

> Couldn't find Brand with 'id'=

And then it is highlighting the following code fragment which I have in 
`/app/models/console.rb`:

```
def full_name
  brand = Brand.find(self.brand_id).name
  "#{brand} #{self.name}"
end
```

Seems like it isn't recognizing `self.brand_id`. Ideas?

Comment: does the `brand_id` column of table `consoles` where `id=1` contain a value? this error indicates an empty value for the `brand_id` column in this row.

Comment: What is your admin console model ?. Try to inspect self using debugger.

Comment: What's the association brand to console?

Comment: Please add post both related models and the related ActiveAdmin file

Comment: You're right, guys—there's no `brand_id`. The point is: I registered that console through ActiveAdmin, and seems like the `select` item of the form is passing to the action `console[brand_id]` instead of just `brand_id`. In other words, `brand_id` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see your `app/models/console.rb` to be sure, but it seems that you should have a `belongs_to` relation and then you could just use that relation ...like this:

```
class Console < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand

  def full_name
    "#{brand.name} #{name}"
  end
end
```

But maybe you should have something guarding that like this:

```
  def full_name
    ("#{brand.name} " if brand.present?) << "#{name}"
  end
```

Comment: `brand.name` is enough—no need for `self`. Do not know how exactly, but it worked!

Comment: `brand` is an accessor method. `self` is implied.

Comment: ...or you can just think of it as Rails Magic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the error with a test for the presence of `brand_id` parameter:

```
def full_name
  if self.brand_id.present?
     brand = Brand.find(self.brand_id).name
     "#{brand} #{self.name}"
  else
     self.name #or other combination of parameters not using the brand model
  end
end
```

Let us know if this helps you.